# How to eliminate heteroskedasticity using the hccm function in R

Tags: r, interpretation, heteroscedasticity

I have a multiple regression model which failed Breusch-Pagan tests, and so I've recalculated the variance using a heteroscedasticity-corrected covariance matrix,
coeftest(lm.model,vcov=hccm(lm.model)).

The result of this is:
    t test of coefficients:

```
                            Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               -365247.87   26636.12 -13.7125  < 2e-16 ***
Size                      -140534.96   13708.09 -10.2520  < 2e-16 ***
Area                        23461.05     540.21  43.4295  < 2e-16 ***
Soil_type                  -31200.69   14655.50  -2.1289  0.03342 *  
Height                      19582.64    1153.52  16.9764  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

I am not sure how to interpret these results. 
1. How can I be sure that I can use these results for inferences?
2. Is there a way to visualise the results? (for example: graph of residuals after transformation)

Comment: Not eliminated, but the standard errors are robust to heteroskedasticity, I.e. they can be used for inference in large samples.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed, how can I be sure I can use this result for further inference? I do have a large sample size.